# How can I split text every 256 characters?

Tags: website, vbscript, links, splitter

I have some text and I want to add a paragraph or a page every 256 characters.

It would also be OK if I could limit the amount of characters for each line to 24 characters.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So, based on the edit, you want a line break every 24 chars and a paragraph break every 256 chars?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest tool for me is [Notepad++ (Npp)](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), with the [TextFX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/TextFX%20v0.26/) plugin.

[image: Notepad++ with TextFX plugin]

1. Open the document or copy the text into a blank document.
2. In any document, Npp or other, type *256*, highlight it and copy it to clipboard with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.
3. Open the *TextFX* menu, go to *TextFX Edit* and click on *ReWrap text...*